# Single page app with REST API architecture

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, reactjs

I built medium sized web application in `Node.js`. At first, I didn't plan it will grow until medium size and didn't know whether it will be used at all. Now, as the client's users started to use it, there is a need for the 2 additional features:

- mobile apps
- single page app

Since until now I used server-side templates (i.e. all of my `API` routes responded with `HTML`), I need to make huge change to support `API` responding with `JSON` just for mobile apps, so I've decided to make refactoring of whole app to support both of these 2 things simultaneously.

Reading through some online resources (namely [Single Page App Book](http://singlepageappbook.com/single-page.html)) and comparing available JavaScript frameworks ([Angular vs Backbone vs React vs Ember](https://gist.github.com/makmanalp/9b7f50aa16d21c2f9d37)), I've came to conclusions presented below. My question is, am I missing something? So, here's how I'm planning to extend my web app:

- I'll rewrite All my UI components in `React`
- All current `API` routes will still respond with `HTML` and that `HTML` will be [server-rendered](https://github.com/mhart/react-server-example) using server-side `React`, but those React UI components will be also included on browser side, which will support single page application features.
- I'll write special `REST` `API`, probably based on [`JSON API`](http://jsonapi.org/) standard for server to communicate with single page application and mobile web applications.
- Both `API` routes (`API` responding with pages - `HTML`, and with data - `JSON`) will be done using `Express` router which will execute *controllers* (server components) for encapsulating combined manipulation of data with *data access layer* (server component).
- *Data access layer* basically consists of `Mongoose` models.

Since this would take longer while to implement and refactor it, I would like to be sure that I'm on the right track. Am I missing here something?

Answer (score 1):

It will make your app easier to build and maintain if you include the flux pattern. I suggest you take a look at some of the starter projects and pick one that compliments your own style. Here is an example from https://github.com/calitek/ReactPatterns React.14/ReFluxSuperAgent. It may seem complex but the pattern offers a good separation of concerns and flexibility.

server.js

```js
'use strict';

let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let express = require('express');
let favicon = require('serve-favicon');

let path = require('path');
let port = Number(3500);

let routes = require('./routes');

let app = express();
let server = app.listen(port);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use('/', express.static('ui-dist'));
app.use('/routes', routes);

app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'ui-dist', 'img', 'favicon.ico')));
app.get('/', function(req, res){ res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html', [], null); });
```

routes.js

```js
'use strict';

let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();

let getSetData = require('./routes/getsetdata');

router.get('/getData', function(req, res) {
 let getDataDone = function(data){ res.send(data); };
 getSetData.getData(getDataDone);
});

router.post('/setData', function(req, res) {
 let setDataDone = function(data){ res.send(data); };
 console.log(req.body);
 getSetData.setData(req.body, setDataDone);
});

module.exports = router;
```

getsetdata.js

```js
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');

var rootDataPath = './data';

var getData = function(doneCallBack) {
 var filePath = rootDataPath + '/basic.json';
 var jsonReadCallBack = function(err, data){
  if (err) doneCallBack('Data readFile error ' + filePath);
  else {
   var jsonData = JSON.parse(data.toString());
   doneCallBack(jsonData);
  }
 };
 fs.readFile(filePath, jsonReadCallBack);
};

var setData = function(data, doneCallBack) {
 var filePath = rootDataPath + '/basic.json';
 var writeFileCallBack = function (err) {
  if (err) console.log('error saving Data.json file ');
  doneCallBack('ok');
 };
 fs.writeFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(data, null, 2), writeFileCallBack);
};

module.exports.getData = getData;
module.exports.setData = setData;
```

index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>ReactPatterns-ReFluxWebSocket</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.min.css"/>

 </head>
 <body class="bodyStyle main">

  <header class="text-center header" >
   <span class="Title">ReactPatterns-ReFluxSuperAgent by Janaka</span>
  </header>

  <section id="react" class="content"></section>

  <script src="app.min.js"></script>

 </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```js
'use strict';

import React  from 'react';
import ReactDom  from 'react-dom';

import AppCtrl from './components/app.ctrl.js';
import Actions from './flux/Actions';
import ApiStore from './flux/Api.Store';

window.ReactDom = ReactDom;

Actions.apiInit();

ReactDom.render( <AppCtrl />, document.getElementById('react') );
```

api.store.js

```js
import Reflux from 'reflux';

import Actions from './Actions';
import ApiFct from './../utils/api.js';

let ApiStoreObject = {
 newData: {
  "React version": "0.14",
  "Project": "ReFluxSuperAgent",
  "currentDateTime": new Date().toLocaleString()
 },
 listenables: Actions,
 apiInit() { ApiFct.setData(this.newData); },
 apiInitDone() { ApiFct.getData(); },
 apiSetData(data) { ApiFct.setData(data); }
}
const ApiStore = Reflux.createStore(ApiStoreObject);
export default ApiStore;
```

api.js

```js
import request from 'superagent';

import Actions from '../flux/Actions';

let uri = 'http://localhost:3500';

module.exports = {
 getData() { request.get(uri + '/routes/getData').end((err, res) => { this.gotData(res.body); }); },
 gotData(data) { Actions.gotData1(data); Actions.gotData2(data); Actions.gotData3(data); },
 setData(data) { request.post('/routes/setData').send(data).end((err, res) => { Actions.apiInitDone(); }) },
};
```

basic.store.js

```js
import Reflux from 'reflux';

import Actions from './Actions';
import AddonStore from './Addon.Store';
import MixinStoreObject from './Mixin.Store';

function _GotData(data) { this.data1 = data; BasicStore.trigger('data1'); }

let BasicStoreObject = {
 init() { this.listenTo(AddonStore, this.onAddonTrigger); },
 data1: {},
 listenables: Actions,
 mixins: [MixinStoreObject],
 onGotData1: _GotData,
 onAddonTrigger() { BasicStore.trigger('data2'); },
 getData1() { return this.data1; },
 getData2() { return AddonStore.data2; },
 getData3() { return this.data3; }
}
const BasicStore = Reflux.createStore(BasicStoreObject);
export default BasicStore;
```

app.ctrl.js

```js
import React from 'react';

import BasicStore from './../flux/Basic.Store';

let AppCtrlSty = {
 height: '100%',
 padding: '0 10px 0 0'
}

const getState = () => {
 return {
  Data1: BasicStore.getData1(),
  Data2: BasicStore.getData2(),
  Data3: BasicStore.getData3()
 };
};

class AppCtrlRender extends React.Component {
  render() {
  let data1 = JSON.stringify(this.state.Data1, null, 2);
  let data2 = JSON.stringify(this.state.Data2, null, 2);
  let data3 = JSON.stringify(this.state.Data3, null, 2);
  return (
   <div id='AppCtrlSty' style={AppCtrlSty}>
    React 1.4 ReFlux with SuperAgent<br/><br/>
    Data1: {data1}<br/><br/>
    Data2: {data2}<br/><br/>
    Data3: {data3}<br/><br/>
   </div>
  );
 }
}

export default class AppCtrl extends AppCtrlRender {
 constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = getState();
 }

 componentDidMount() { this.unsubscribe = BasicStore.listen(this.storeDidChange.bind(this)); }
 componentWillUnmount() { this.unsubscribe(); }
 storeDidChange(id) {
  switch (id) {
   case 'data1': this.setState({Data1: BasicStore.getData1()}); break;
   case 'data2': this.setState({Data2: BasicStore.getData2()}); break;
   case 'data3': this.setState({Data3: BasicStore.getData3()}); break;
   default: this.setState(getState());
  }
 }
}
```